# NetLogo in-radius

Tags: netlogo

i have this code and it's not clear to me what is it doing:

```
patches-own [ field ]

let a max-one-of patches in-radius b [field]
ifelse ([field] of a > 0.1) and ([field] of a < 0.5)
[
;; do something
]
[
;; do something else
]
```

Thanks,
Marco

Comment: Let a maximum of one given (number/ patch) and put it in field. If the given is between .1 and .5, does something. If not, does something else. And found you this: http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/in-radius.html

Comment: @Evan it doesn't "put it in field", this code never sets `field`.

Answer (score 0):

This is apparently code to be run by a turtle or patch, it isn't apparent which.

`patches in-radius b` is an agentset of the circle of patches, of radius `b`, around the calling agent. `max-one-of ... [field]` finds the patch in that agentset that has the largest value for `field`. That patch is then stored in the new local variable `a`. (A better name than `a` might have been `winner` or `peak` or `best-patch`.)

`[field] of a` is then that maximum value of `field`, the same one that `max-one-of` found. The `ifelse` checks to see if that value is in a certain range or not, and does something different, depending.

Does the code inside the `ifelse` make any further use of `a`? If it does, cool. If it doesn't, well, the code could be more easily and simply written as:

```
let m max [field] of patches in-radius b
ifelse m > 0.1 and m < 0.5
[
;; do something
]
[
;; do something else
]
```

perhaps seeing it in this form will help making the meaning clear.